# How to get User Time Zone in Wordpress?

Tags: php, date, date-time, timestamp, timezones

how can I get user Time Zone in Wordpress if you don't know  where the user comes from.

Let's say if a user is in USA I need to get USA Time Zone, if the user is in Germany I need to get Germany Time Zone.

Comment: How do you know where a user is coming from?

Comment: I don't know, I need to detect it programmatically, but I don't know how.

Comment: Ok, so that is where you need to start. Searching for "wordpress find country of visitor" already yields a couple of results. What have you tried of these and where are you currently failing?

Comment: I tried this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip) but it returns empty `ip_info("Visitor", "Country");`

Comment: Doing this `echo( ip_info()["country"]);` works

Comment: As commented [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355808/serve-visitor-post-time-adjusted-to-their-timezone), there is no reliable way of doing this. also getting a country wont give you the time zone per se, there is no "USA Time Zone"

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress is a server-side framework/CMS, it likely doesn't have the functionality you're looking for. If you're looking for ways to obtain this information, the most reliable would likely [be to ask the user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797/759563).

To make it as painless as possible for the user, this functionality could be achieved via client-side scripting (ie. JavaScript) where you attempt to [infer the user's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1809974/759563):

```
-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

And then ask the user to confirm that it is the correct timezone. Keep in mind, client side code is run on the user's machine and can be disabled entirely.